# SOLR - return records based on the result of other query

Tags: solr

I store in SOLR information about jobs, like id:long, city:string
Would it be possible to send to SOLR job id and it would return other jobs based on the same city? I know I can make 2 calls to SOLR but can it be done within one call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to search by *job id* and then load other records matched by *city*. This should be doable with [Join Query Parser](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Other+Parsers#OtherParsers-JoinQueryParser).

Answer (score 0):

You can **AND** the both filter based on job id and city in one call. Let me know if you need more info.